# Display image with ruby processing

Tags: ruby, processing

So this seems simple from all the samples I saw on github and elsewhere but sadly I can't get a simple image to display with ruby processing.  Any help would be much appreciated.

My code:

```
attr_reader :img

def setup
  size(600, 600)
  @img = loadImage("chess.jpg")
end

def draw
  image(@img, 10, 10)
end
```

The code is in ~/RP-image/scratchpad.rb    The jpg is in ~/RP-image/data/chess.jpg
I've tried every permutation of load_image  loadimage  loadImage etc  I get the response in terminal of:

```
The file "chess.jpg" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException

processing.core.PGraphics.image(processing/core/PGraphics.java:3572)
processing.core.PApplet.image(processing/core/PApplet.java:12773)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:483)
RUBY.draw(image-scratchpad.rb:8)
processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(processing/core/PApplet.java:2386)
processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(processing/core/PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
processing.core.PApplet.run(processing/core/PApplet.java:2256)
java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
```

As far as I know you dont need to "add an image to the sketch" other than load it with the loadimage command.

Comment: have you tried `@img = loadImage("data/chess.jpg")`?

Comment: @uri-agassi  No luck.  Just tried it and I get the same error of NullPointerException.

Comment: Maybe the full path to the file?  @img = loadImage("/Users/DChaps/path/to/your/project/data/chess.jpg")

Comment: @LupineDev  Son of a...  That worked.  See the code at [Github-Learning Processing](https://github.com/ruby-processing/learning-processing-with-ruby/blob/master/chapter_15/01_hello_world_image.rb)   They dont use the full directory at all.  Just the name and a comment that your supposed to put the image files in the 'data' directory.  Can you add your suggestion as a solution so i can mark it complete.

Comment: I just tried it and using the full path it will allow you to load an image from anywhere that you have access to.  No need to have a data folder inside the project folder.